# How to generate a Sequence From a Given sequence

Tags: r, sequence-generators

I am trying to generate a sequence

**for Example as shown below ::**

```
> s
[1]  1  5  7 10 

>s.Generated_Seq 
[1]  1 2 9 10 13 14 19 20 

> s
[1]  2 5 7 10 

>s.Generated_Seq 
[1]  3 4 9 10 13 14 19 20
```

**Note :** when sequence is started from 1 its generated sequence should start from 1 only 
and if sequence is started from 2 or 6 or 15 or any number generated sequence should be multiple of that number.

Comment: @akrun Yes Sir , its a sequence of number and i need to generated a sequence where other sequence is multiple of of 2. and seq start from 1 seq should start from 1 itself. and other with multiple of 2 .Thank you for your time sir appreciated

Comment: I posted your logic as a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a function that takes a `vector` as input argument and returns the transformed output based on the logic described

```
f1 <- function(vec){
  if(vec[1]==1) {  #if the first element is 1
   #append the first element with the twice multiplied other elements
      c(vec[1], 2*vec[-1]) 
   #or else just multiply the vector with the first element
  } else vec*vec[1]
 }

f1(v1)
#[1]  1 10 14 20

f1(v2)
#[1]  4 10 14 20
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1, 5, 7, 10)
v2 <- c(2, 5, 7, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v1 <- c(1, 5, 7, 10)
v2 <- c(2, 5, 7, 10)

ifelse(rep(v1[1],length(v1))==1,c(v1[1],2*v1[-1]), 2*v1)
# [1]  1 10 14 20

ifelse(rep(v2[1],length(v2))==1,c(v2[1],2*v2[-1]), 2*v2)
# [1]  4 10 14 20
```

The reason for doing `rep(v2[1],length(v2))` instead of just doing `v2[1]==1` is that `ifelse` returns a value with the same length as ‘test’. So we basically do the test same number of times as length of vector so that we can return the complete vector from `ifelse`

Comment: i just noticed @akrun's answer is basically the same as mine!

Comment: @akrun i need to generate a sequence 
Example1=seq(1,5,7,10) 
Generated sequence is (1,2,9,10,13,14,19,20) 
Example2=seq(2,5,7,10) 
Generated sequence is (3,4,9,10,13,14,19,20) please do guide me on this.